# How to change value of a select box in angular2 unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I have an Angular2 component that contains a select box that looks like

```
<select [(ngModel)]="envFilter" class="form-control" name="envSelector" (ngModelChange)="onChangeFilter($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let env of envs" [ngValue]="env">{{env}}</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to write a unit test for the ngModelChange event.  This is my latest failing attempt

```
it("should filter and show correct items", async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.name("envSelector"));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        makeResponse([hist2, longhist]);
        comp.envFilter = 'env3';
        el.triggerEventHandler('change', {});
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(comp.displayedHistory).toEqual(longhist);
        });
    });
```

The part I am having trouble with is that changing the value of the underlying model `comp.envFilter = 'env3';` does not trigger the change method.  I added `el.triggerEventHandler('change', {});` but this throws `Failed: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: By is not defined`.  I cannot find any hints in the documentation... any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as the error. It seems like you just need to import `By`. This is not something that is global. It should be imported from the following module

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

As far as the testing part, this is what I have been able to figure out. When you change a value in a the component, you need to trigger a change detection to update the view. You do this with `fixture.detectChanges()`. Once this is done, *normally* the view should be updated with the value.

From testing something similar to your example, it seems this is not the case though. It seems there is still some asynchronous task going on after the change detection. Say we have the following

```
const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));

comp.selectedValue = 'a value';
fixture.DetectChanges();
expect(select.nativeElement.value).toEqual('1: a value');
```

This doesn't seem to work. It appears there is some async going on causing the value not to be set yet. So we need to wait for the async tasks by calling `fixture.whenStable`

```
comp.selectedValue = 'a value';
fixture.DetectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(select.nativeElement.value).toEqual('1: a value');
});
```

The above would work. But now we need to trigger the change event as that doesn't happen automatically.

```
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(select.nativeElement.value).toEqual('1: a value');

  dispatchEvent(select.nativeElement, 'change');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // component expectations here
  });
});
```

Now we have another asynchronous task from the event. So we need to stabilize it again

Below is a complete test that I tested with. It's a refactor of the example from the [source code integration tests](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/forms/test/template_integration_spec.ts). They used `fakeAsync` and `tick` which is similar to using `async` and `whenStable`. But with `fakeAsync`, you can't use `templateUrl`, so I though it would be best to refactor it to use `async`.

Also the source code tests does kind of a double one way testing, first testing model to view, then view to model. While it looks like your test was trying to do kind of a two-way test, from model around back to model. So I refactored it a bit to suite your example better.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, getTestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { dispatchEvent } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser_util';

@Component({
  selector: 'ng-model-select-form',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (ngModelChange)="onSelected($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
  `
})
class NgModelSelectForm {
  selectedCity: {[k: string]: string} = {};
  cities: any[] = [];

  onSelected(value) {
  }
}

describe('component: NgModelSelectForm', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ NgModelSelectForm ]
    });
  });

  it('should go from model to change event', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NgModelSelectForm);
    const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(comp, 'onSelected');
    comp.cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
    comp.selectedCity = comp.cities[1];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      dispatchEvent(select.nativeElement, 'change');
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(comp.onSelected).toHaveBeenCalledWith({name : 'NYC'});
        console.log('after expect NYC');
      });
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: This answer is out-of-date due to syntax changes. Refer to Iain's answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391665/2959821

Answer (score 11):

I found peeskillet's answer very useful but sadly it is a little out of date as the way to dispatch an Event has been changed. I also found there was an unnecessary call to whenStable(). So here is an updated test using peeskillet's setup:

```
    it('should go from model to change event', async(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NgModelSelectForm);
        const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        spyOn(comp, 'onSelected');
        comp.cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
        comp.selectedCity = comp.cities[1];
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));

        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            select.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(comp.onSelected).toHaveBeenCalledWith({name : 'NYC'});
            console.log('after expect NYC');
        });
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks Iain: following lit up my unit test having set select.nativeElement.selectedIndex: "select.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));" :-)

Answer (score 8):

Look this example, from angular source (template_integration_spec.ts)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ng-model-select-form',
  template: `
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
      <option *ngFor="let c of cities" [ngValue]="c"> {{c.name}} </option>
    </select>
  `
})
class NgModelSelectForm {
  selectedCity: {[k: string]: string} = {};
  cities: any[] = [];
}



  it('with option values that are objects', fakeAsync(() => {
       const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NgModelSelectForm);
       const comp = fixture.componentInstance;
       comp.cities = [{'name': 'SF'}, {'name': 'NYC'}, {'name': 'Buffalo'}];
       comp.selectedCity = comp.cities[1];
       fixture.detectChanges();
       tick();

       const select = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select'));
       const nycOption = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('option'))[1];

       // model -> view
       expect(select.nativeElement.value).toEqual('1: Object');
       expect(nycOption.nativeElement.selected).toBe(true);

       select.nativeElement.value = '2: Object';
       dispatchEvent(select.nativeElement, 'change');
       fixture.detectChanges();
       tick();

       // view -> model
       expect(comp.selectedCity['name']).toEqual('Buffalo');
     }));
```

Comment: Please explain why this example answers the question.

Comment: This answer helped, especially the `'2: Object'` part but I don't know the reasoning behind using it.

Comment: Link to the source https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/572b54967c969c88c61970650fb857afc1d74f8a/packages/forms/test/value_accessor_integration_spec.ts#L245-L268

Comment: This answer is out-of-date due to syntax changes. Refer to Iain's answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47391665/2959821

Answer (score 2):

Same problem as raised by OP but slightly different code.

Works in Angular 7.

HTML:

```
<select id="dashboard-filter" class="form-control" name="dashboard-filter" [ngModel]="dashboardFilterValue" (ngModelChange)="onFilterChange($event)"
              [disabled]="disabled">
  <option *ngFor="let filter of dashboardFilters" [ngValue]="filter.value">{{ filter.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Unit test:

```
it('onFilterChange', () => {

  // ensure dropdown is enabled
  expect(component.disabled).toBe(false)

  // spies
  spyOn(component, 'onFilterChange').and.callThrough()
  spyOn(component.filterChange, 'emit')

  // initially the 3rd item in the dropdown is selected
  const INITIAL_FILTER_INDEX = 2
  // we want to select the 5th item in the dropdown
  const FILTER_INDEX = 4
  // the expected filter value is the value of the 5th dashboard filter (as used to populate the dropdown)
  const EXPECTED_FILTER_VALUE = getDashboardFiltersData.dashboardFilters[FILTER_INDEX].value

  // handle on the dropdown
  const filterDropdown = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select')).nativeElement

  // let bindings complete
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {

    // ensure filterDropdown.value is stable
    expect(filterDropdown.value).toContain(getDashboardFiltersData.dashboardFilters[INITIAL_FILTER_INDEX].value)

    // update filterDropdown.value and dispatch change event
    filterDropdown.value = filterDropdown.options[FILTER_INDEX].value
    filterDropdown.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))

    // check component data
    expect(component.dashboardFilterValue).toBe(EXPECTED_FILTER_VALUE)
    expect(component.dashboardFilterChangeInProgress).toBe(false)

    // check spies
    expect(component.onFilterChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(EXPECTED_FILTER_VALUE)
    expect(setDashboardFilterSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(EXPECTED_FILTER_VALUE)
    expect(component.filterChange.emit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true)
  })
})
```

Comment: Having to do `.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` manually is really aweful. No criticism on this answer though. Happy I found it.