# angular tests passing before async call has completed?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have the following angular (4) test which should be testing a service, however, it seems to be passing before the Observable returns and `expect` get's hit.

```
   it('should enter the assertion', inject(
        [ MockBackend, CellService ],
        ( backend: MockBackend, s: CellService ) => {
            const urls = [];

            backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
                const req = connection.request;
                urls.push(req.url);
                if (req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === '/api/getTest') {
                    connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions('enter mocked content')));
                }
            });
            s.getCell('powders').subscribe(val => expect(true).toBeFalsy())
        })
    );
```

I tried adding async/await, but that didn't make a difference. How can I do this?

Update:

This code passes too ...

```
it('should enter the assertion', async(inject(
    [ MockBackend, CellService ],
    ( backend: MockBackend, s: CellService ) => {
        const urls = [];

        backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
            const req = connection.request;
            urls.push(req.url);
            if (req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === '/api/getTest') {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions('enter mocked content')));
            }
        });
        s.getCell('powders').subscribe(val => expect(true).toBeFalsy())
    })
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the test in Angular's `async`

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';

                         ---==== vvvv ===----
it('should enter the assertion', async(inject(
    [ MockBackend, CellService ],
    ( backend: MockBackend, s: CellService ) => {
        ...
    })
));
```

This will wrap the test in a test zone, which will allow Angular to actually wait for all the asynchronous tasks to complete before finishing the test.

**See also:**

- [Angular 2 Testing - Async function call - when to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40126729/2587435)
- [Test a component with an async service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-async-service)
- [What is the difference between fakeAsync and async in angular2 testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42971537/2587435)

## UPDATE

Try it with `fakeAsycn`/`tick`

```
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('should enter the assertion', fakeAsync(inject(
    [ MockBackend, CellService ],
    ( backend: MockBackend, s: CellService ) => {
        ...

        let value;
        s.getCell('powders').subscribe(val => {
          value = val;
        })
        tick();
        expect(val).toBeTruthy();
    })
));
```

It *should* work with `async`, but using `fakeAsync` makes it a little easier to debug, since every thing is synchronous.

If it still doesn't work, then you may need to check the logic somewhere else. One of the checks I would make is here

```
req.method === RequestMethod.Get && req.url === '/api/getTest'
```

Are you sure both of these pass? If not, there will be no response.

Comment: See my updated question, I tried this approach and am still not seeing the expected behaviour, have I done something wrong?

Comment: See my update. Make sure the condition passes. If not, there will be no response.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use Jasmine `done()` callback here.

First, get rid off injectors in the spec and use `TestBed.get(serviceToken)` in `beforeEach` section.

Second, pass done as parameter of spec function

```
it('should use asynchronous', done => {
  s.method().subscribe(result => {
    expect(result).toBe(...);
    done();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitForAsync` which is intended exactly for this and works both with observables and promises.

> Wraps a test function in an asynchronous test zone. The test will automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone are done. Can be used to wrap an inject call. ([doc](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync))

```
it('...', waitForAsync(inject([AClass], (object) => {
  object.doSomething.subscribe(() => {
    expect(...);
  })
})));
```