# What is the difference between angular testing async+whenStable and fakeAsync+tick?

Tags: angular, testing

I understand that the `async` and `fakeAsync` methods setup some kind of listener that records all async operations so that the angular testing framework can use `whenStable` and `tick()` to manage waiting for all that stuff to finish. I think thats correct?

The thing I am struggling to understand is whether there is actually an execution order difference - because if not why offer both?

This has brought me to learning about JS macro tasks and Micro tasks and I am wondering if this area is where the two approaches differ?

Comment: You may also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971537/what-is-the-difference-between-fakeasync-and-async-in-angular2-testing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an abstract from **[Testing Asynchronous Code - CodeCraft](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/)**

### [`async` + `whenStable`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_code_async_code_and_code_whenstable_code):

**Consider this piece of code:**

```
it('Button label via async() and whenStable()', async(() => { 
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('Login');
  spyOn(authService, 'isAuthenticated').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => { 
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('Logout');
  });
  component.ngOnInit();
}));
```

`async` function executes the code inside its body in a special **`async` test zone**. This intercepts and keeps track of all promises created in its body.

Only when all of those pending promises have been resolved does it then resolves the promise returned from `whenStable`.

You can use this to avoid using Jasmine's spy mechanism of detecting when a promise has been resolved.

This mechanism is slightly better than using the plain Jasmine solution but there is another version which gives us fine grained control and also allows us to lay out our test code as if it were synchronous.

---

### [`fakeAsync` + `tick`](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/#_code_fakeasync_code_and_code_tick_code):

**Now consider this piece of code:**

```
it('Button label via fakeAsync() and tick()', fakeAsync(() => { 
  expect(el.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('Login');
  spyOn(authService, 'isAuthenticated').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  component.ngOnInit();

  tick(); 
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(el.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('Logout');
}));
```

Just like `async`, the `fakeAsync` function executes the code inside its body in a special ***fake* `async` test zone**. This intercepts and keeps track of all promises created in its body.

The `tick()` function blocks execution and simulates the passage of time until all pending asynchronous activities complete.

So when we call `tick()` the application sits and waits for the promises to be resolved and then lets execution move to the next line.

The main advantage of using this is that it makes the code more linear as if we were executing synchronous code, there are no callbacks to confuse the mind and everything is simpler to understand.

### Conclusion:

There are three mechanisms we can use to test asynchronous code:

1. The jasmine's `done` function and spy callbacks. This works but expects us to know about all the promises in our application and be able to hook into them.
2. We can use the Angular `async` and `whenStable` functions, we don’t need to track the promises ourselves but we still need to lay our code out via callback functions which can be hard to read.
3. We can use the Angular `fakeAsync` and `tick` functions, this additionally lets us lay out our `async` test code as if it were synchronous.

These points would make you think that why use `async` + `whenStable` if it's hard to read. Why not simply use `fakeAsync` + `tick` instead? Well one of the reasons would be beause of this:

> **Important**
> `fakeAsync` does have some drawbacks, it [**doesn’t track XHR requests**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8280#issuecomment-227499150) for instance.

You can read more about this on this [**GitHub Thread**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8280).

Comment: What I am understanding from that is that they are exactly the same but one is a nicer syntax which begs the question why have the worse syntax as an option?

also you can still do fixture.whenStable inside a fakeAsync zone but I dont know if that works?

Comment: Let me try to answer that by updating the answer.

Comment: @Craig, I've updated the answer. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You're awesome.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Super nice answer. Just wondering why didn't you use standard async/await in your first example instead of Promise.then? I believe then there is almost no difference in both approaches.

Comment: Do note that `async + whenStable` can be considerably slower in some cases and could potentially slow the whole test suite down if used incorrectly.