# When to use waitForAsync in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

From documentation we can read:

`waitForAsync(fn: Function): (done: any) => any`

> Wraps a test function in an asynchronous test zone. The test will
> automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone
> are done. Can be used to wrap an inject call.

I could not understand, when to use `waitForAsync` function? What's the difference between `waitForAsync` vs (`async` or `fakeAsync`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between fakeAsync and async in angular2 testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971537/what-is-the-difference-between-fakeasync-and-async-in-angular2-testing)

Comment: Hey, sorry but no It's a good point, but the main question is for a `waitForAsync` method which is not described in article which you posted

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In Angular 10.1.0, `waitForAsync()` has replaced `async()` [to avoid confusion](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/37583), but is otherwise exactly the same.  Any documentation you see that discusses using `async()` will also apply to `waitForAsync()`.  `async()` has been marked as deprecated and will be removed entirely in version 12.

Comment: The deprecated `async()` function in Angular's `@angular/core/testing` library (https://angular.io/api/core/testing/async) should not be confused with the native `async/await` in JavaScript and the default testing schematic in modern Angular. So if you see the `async/await` usage in newly constructed unit tests, this _is_ acceptable and different. One thing is for sure the original `async()` function had poor naming from Angular and added confusion.

Answer (score 8):

*Wraps a test function in an asynchronous test zone. The test will automatically complete when all asynchronous calls within this zone are done. Can be used to wrap an inject call.*

So you dont have to manually call `done()` callback passed as an argument to mark test had finished or use `fakeAsync()` and other helper functions `from '@angular/core/testing'`

```js
it('...', waitForAsync(inject([AClass], (object) => {
  object.doSomething.then(() => {
    expect(...);
  })
});
```

See [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/waitForAsync).